# How to restart React - Native Application on button click event

Tags: react-native

I am try to Restart Application on click of button when user click on logout button then Application is Restart

Comment: To logout you should check the doc about Authentication flows https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/ . You should not restart the app to logout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this library `react-native-restart`

Example usage:

```
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart'; 

RNRestart.Restart();
```

Comment: yes i know its working but i want to restart Application without use of any node package

Comment: Why you should want to do react native without using node package?

Comment: it was clear AsyncStorage while restart app also in ios some time its not working

Comment: I had problems with version 0.0.22 so I installed older version and it was fine - 
npm install react-native-restart@0.0.20

Answer (score 6):

You can use NativeModules.

```
import { NativeModules } from "react-native";

NativeModules.DevSettings.reload();
```

Comment: I believe this is only on RN .63 (which is fine, I just wanted to let people know)

Comment: This only works in developer mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this library `react-native-restart`. But it would be a very absurd behaviour to restart app on logout instead you can check out *switch navigator* of **react-navigation**. [Checkout this link.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html)

Comment: Switch navigation was deprecated. Check the doc about Authentication flows instead https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

Answer (score 0):

**Installing The Library**

Using React Native version below 0.40? use version 0.0.1. Otherwise, use version 0.0.2.

**RN < 0.40**

> npm install react-native-restart@0.0.1 --save

**RN >= 0.40**

> npm install react-native-restart --save

**Usage**

```
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart'; // Import package from node modules

// Immediately reload the React Native Bundle
RNRestart.Restart();
```

Restart();

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to restart the Application is by using NativeModules.

```
import {nativemodules} from 'react-native';
```

and then

use `NativeModules.DevSettings.reload();` in on Press or on Click function

Answer (score 0):

**import `{DevSettings}` from 'react-native';**

**DevSettings.reload()**

For me Works!

https://reactnative.dev/docs/devsettings#reload